# React Native center Animated Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, expo

I've been using expo to develop some cool programs and I'm trying to build a clone of Twitter. I got a little problem while building the loading animation of twitter app.
I'm using IonIcons "twitter-logo" to build this and the problem is that the Icon doesn't stay centered like in the original app, it gets animated weirdly.

**To test it, just paste the code bellow to your App.js and you'll see the animation.**

If you don't have Expo, just change the import to react-native-vecto-icons.

```
import React from "react";
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";

AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Icon);

export default class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isAnimating: false,
      iconSize: new Animated.Value(60)
    };
  }

  startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.iconSize, {
      toValue: 1500,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: Easing.back(0.8)
    }).start(() => this.setState({ isAnimating: false }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let x = setTimeout(() => {
      let isLoading = !this.state.isLoading;
      let isAnimating = !this.state.isAnimating;
      this.setState({ isLoading, isAnimating });
      this.startAnimation();
      clearTimeout(x);
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading || this.state.isAnimating)
      return (
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            backgroundColor: "#1b95e0"
          }}
        >
          <AnimatedIcon
            name={"logo-twitter"}
            style={{
              alignSelf: "center",
              fontSize: this.state.iconSize
            }}
            color={"#fff"}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      );

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>TWITTER APP :)</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE ANIMATION](https://gfycat.com/SoggyHarshFruitfly)

Comment: You would be better using an image of the twitter icon rather than using the font, that way you can align it exactly.

Comment: I've tried using an Image and it worked, but I want to use Icons because I plan on doing this with other Icons in future apps.

Answer (score 1):

Just change alignSelf property in style of Animated Icon to textAlign. That will make Icon in center of screen.Below is updated code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Easing, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons as Icon } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Icon);

export default class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isAnimating: false,
      iconSize: new Animated.Value(60),
    };
  }

  startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.iconSize, {
      toValue: 1500,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: Easing.back(0.8),
    }).start(() => this.setState({ isAnimating: false }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let x = setTimeout(() => {
      let isLoading = !this.state.isLoading;
      let isAnimating = !this.state.isAnimating;
      this.setState({ isLoading, isAnimating });
      this.startAnimation();
      clearTimeout(x);
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading || this.state.isAnimating)
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#1b95e0',
          }}>
          <AnimatedIcon
            name={'logo-twitter'}
            style={{
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontSize: this.state.iconSize,
            }}
            color={'#fff'}
          />
        </View>
      );

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>TWITTER APP :)</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, did not work on iOS, same comportament as posted before on the gif.

Comment: change textAlign :'center' to alignSelf:'center' in Animated.Icon style.It will solve issue in Ios too.